# Proof that linearly dependent rows/columns of $A \implies \det(A) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, proof-explanation

I have seen in a few textbooks of proofs of $\det(A) = 0$ if the rows/columns of $A$ are linearly dependent from the properties of the determinant, but I have yet to see a proof that $\det(A) = 0$ from the definition of the determinant: $$\det(A) = \sum \text{sgn}(P)a_{1\alpha}a_{2\beta}...a_{n\omega}$$

where $(\alpha, \beta, ..., \omega)$ are permutations of the columns of $A$. And since all the properties of $\det$ follow from it's definition, I find that proving $\det(A) = 0$ if the rows/columns of $A$ are linearly dependent from the properties of the determinant, to be somewhat unsatisfactory.

Can someone provide a proof from the Leibniz Expansion definition of the determinant, that I provided above, of the result that $\det(A) = 0$ if the rows/columns of $A$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: What is that "$\det(P)$" factor in *your* definition of $\;\det A\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, $\det(P)$ is the determinant of the Permutation matrix given by the permutation of the columns $(\alpha, \beta, ..., \omega)$

Comment: Then the notation $\text{sgn}(P)$ may be better?

Comment: @Perturbative Thanks. Fei Li explains my point better as Libniz' definition of determinant uses the sygnum (sign) function, not other matrix's determinant within the **definition** of determinant, which imo could easily be seen as a circular definition.

Comment: Then could you please edit your notation, cause otherwise I fear the question is prone to get downvote.

Comment: Write one column as a linear combination of the others, plug that into the formula, expand and see what happens. If that helps, do the case $n=3$ explicitly. You should see how pairs with opposite signs cancel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comments below, this hint has been expanded to a complete solution.

#### Step 1.

> **Proposition.**  Suppose $A$ is a square matrix and $B$ is the matrix defined by interchanging two columns of $A$. Then
> $$\det A=-\det B.$$

*Proof.*  Consider the definition. every term of $\det B$ in the sum is $(-1)$ times the corresponding term for $\det A$. Thus the whole $\det B$ differs from $\det A$ by $(-1)$.

#### Step 2.

> **Proposition.**
>
> 1. If $A$ is a square matrix that has two equal columns, then $\det A=0$.
> 2. If we multiply a column of $A$ by $\lambda$, then $\det A=\lambda(\det A).$

*Proof.*

1. Interchanging the two equal columns of $A$ gives the original matrix $A$. Then from **step 1** we have
   $$\det A=-\det A,$$ which implies that $\det A=0.$
2. This should be obvious from the definition.

#### Step 3.

> **Proposition.** Let $A$ be a square matrix. Let $A'$ be obtained from $A$ by adding a multiple of one column to a different column. Then $\det A'=\det A$.

*Proof.* To convince oneself that the above is right, one first try some explicit calculations. Let's do that for $n=2$ and $n=3$.

For $n=2$, let $A=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1\\x_2&y_2\end{pmatrix}$, and let $$A'=\begin{pmatrix}x_1+\lambda y_1&y_1\\x_2+\lambda y_2&y_2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now $$\begin{split}\det A'&=(x_1+\lambda y_1)y_2-y_1(x_2+\lambda y_2)\\  &=x_1y_2+\lambda y_1y_2-x_2y_1-\lambda y_1y_2\\  &=x_1y_2-x_2y_1\\ &=\det A.\end{split}$$

For $n=3$, we let $A=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3&y_3&z_3\end{pmatrix}$. We verify the claim for $$A'=\begin{pmatrix}x_1+\lambda z_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2+\lambda z_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3+\lambda z_3&y_3&z_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now $$\begin{split}\det A'= &(x_1+\lambda z_1)y_2z_3+(x_3+\lambda z_3)y_1z_2+(x_2+\lambda z_2)y_3z_1\\  &-(x_3+\lambda z_3)y_2z_1-(x_1+\lambda z_1)y_3z_2-(x_2+\lambda z_2)y_1z_3.\end{split}$$

Collecting terms that contain $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$:

$\begin{cases}\lambda z_1y_2z_3+\lambda z_3y_1z_2+\lambda z_2y_3z_1\\ -\lambda z_1y_2z_3-\lambda z_3y_1z_2-\lambda z_2y_3z_1\end{cases}$

so that those terms are canceled out, and what left is the $\det A$.

For a general proof, let's look again at the $n=3$ case.  After one understand this, other $n$'s are just a play of notations.

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3&y_3&z_3\end{pmatrix}.$$ To maximize our simplification of the messy notations in the definition of determinant, we have chosen different alphabets $x,y,z$ to name each column, so that we don't have to use numbers to name those columns. Furthermore, let's use $\sigma$ to denote the permutation, so that the definition of determinant of $A$ becomes: $$\det A=\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma)x_{\sigma(1)}y_{\sigma(2)}z_{\sigma(3)},$$ where the sum is over all permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ (Think of the $1,2,3$ in the $\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(3)$ as the domain of the function $\sigma$). Using this notation, it is pretty clear what the effect of adding a multiple of one column to another is:

Let $$A'=\begin{pmatrix}x_1+\lambda z_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2+\lambda z_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3+\lambda z_3&y_3&z_3\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then
$$\begin{split}\det A' &=\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma)\left(x_{\sigma(1)}+\lambda z_{\sigma(1)}\right)y_{\sigma(2)}z_{\sigma(3)}\\ &=\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma)x_{\sigma(1)}y_{\sigma(2)}z_{\sigma(3)}+\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma)\lambda z_{\sigma(1)}y_{\sigma(2)}z_{\sigma(3)}\\ &=\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma)x_{\sigma(1)}y_{\sigma(2)}z_{\sigma(3)}+\lambda\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma)z_{\sigma(1)}y_{\sigma(2)}z_{\sigma(3)}.\end{split}$$

The second summand is, *by definition*, the determinant of the following matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}z_1&y_1&z_1\\z_2&y_2&z_2\\z_3&y_3&z_3\end{pmatrix}$$

which is $0$ by our **step 2.** What left is, again by definition, the determinant of $A$. Thus $\det A'=\det A$, and the proof is complete.

There is really no need for me to write out the general proof for arbitrary $n$, which add nothing to the above proof other than heavy notations. You can write that out by yourself if you wish.

#### Step 4.

Suppose the columns (or rows, but it's more natural for me to think about columns) of a square matrix $A$, denoted by $(C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_n)$, are linearly dependent. This means that one of $C_i$ can be expressed as a nontrivial linear combination of the other columns. For concreteness, let's say $C_1=\lambda_2C_2+\cdots+\lambda_nC_n$, where not all of $\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are zero. Then since by **step 3,** adding a multiple of one column to another does not change the determinant of $A$, we can add $-\lambda_nC_n,\ldots,-\lambda_3C_3$ to $C_1$ without changing the determinant. This leaves us $C_1=\lambda_2C_2$, from which $\det A=0$ follows by **step 2.**

Comment: The question is not about one row being a multiple of another row, but about some linear dependency existing among all the rows.

Comment: Christian Blatter is right, but since adding a multiple of one column/row to another different one does not change the determinant, one can eventually reduce the case to two linearly dependent columns/rows. To see this, Carsten S's suggestion is useful: just write out the calculations for $2\times 2$ or $3\times 3$ matrices explicitly.

Comment: It's not at all obvious from the OP's definition of the determinant that row operations leave it unchanged. That's why I made a comment to your answer.